# In Laravel how do you return a view when using Post?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am new to Laravel, and i am trying to return a view after I submit a form but I get an error saying

`The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

I am not sure how to fix it, I have tried `return redirect()->route('formm');`

This is in my HTML code

```
          <form action={{ route("formget") }} method="post">
              <input type="text" name='name'>
              <input type="text" name='email'>
              <input type="submit">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
          </form>
```

This is on my Route

```
Route::post('/fetchget',"temm@fetchAndDis")
->name('formget');
```

This is on my Controller

```
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => "required|min:5",
            "name" => "required|min:1"
        ]);

        return view("formget");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have more than one route named `formget`?  There's no inherent need to redirect, a post route can return response data, such as a view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make another route that can return a view. And redirect from your controller post method to this route.
Make Route:

```
Route::get('/showView',"temm@showview")->name('showView');
```

in showView Method return view:

```
public function showview{
   return view('your_view_path');
}
```

And your controller Post Method just returns redirect that route:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => "required|min:5",
        "name" => "required|min:1"
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('showView');
}
```

Comment: How can I pass multiple parameters from function called using POST method, to the function called using GET method (`showview` in this case) so I can later pass them to the view itself? I have 4 parameters and I don't them to be passed through URL

Comment: @nikname You can pass the parameters in the form submit. But if the parameters required in route arguments then you can do like this `route('showView',['name'=>$name,'email'=>$email])`

Comment: Not exactly. If I pass them like that, then I should append them to GET route, and that is not what I want. Route `showView` is GET request and I can't pass those parameters in a body of request. And I do not have simple parameters like `$name` of type `String`, but `arrays` and `collections`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply. Just create another route that return a view that you wanted. And finally redirect to this route from your post controller..